# One DataTable For Two Pages Odd and Even In Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Report in VS 2012 and have a report with multil columns, now How do I design in Crystal Report to:

1. Even page Ex: 2 and 4 will show column1, column2
2. Odd page Ex: 3 and 5 will show column3, column4

What can I do with Page Header Section and Detail Section to do above issue?

Thanks!
Look like this:
[Data in two pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaQj3.png)

I tried: [CRDemo](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=3008B37BE95F70CE%211893)

In my project, when my data have 100 record then I want page 2 show record 1
then page 3 also show it. But now, it does'nt do that. See project for more detail

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Place both the columns in detail section now in supress formula of the columns write condition

Column 1 and column 2

```
If pagenumber/2=0
Then true
Else false
```

Column3 and column 4

```
If pagenumber/2=0
Then false
Else true
```

Comment: I do that, But not the same above Example, Please view 2 images I've attach on main post

Comment: solution should work as expected, let me know what have you done?